Custom Identity service registration error
I'm trying to look for user data after the login process:
try
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

using this one.
but user can only get the default identityuser data.
because of managers:
private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
    ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
    _userManager = userManager;
}

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();


I tried changing the IdentityUser service registration to custom one
builder.Services.AddIdentity<Account_Model, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();

private readonly SignInManager<Account_Model> _signInManager;
private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;
private readonly UserManager<Account_Model> _userManager;

public LoginModel(SignInManager<Account_Model> signInManager,
    ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
    UserManager<Account_Model> userManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
    _userManager = userManager;
}

    public class ApplicationDBContext : IdentityDbContext<Account_Model>

now i can use the user variable to find the data from custom model:
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

but ofcourse its gonna look for IdentityUser service registration since its the default for identity role. but i thought its gonna work since the identityuser is inherited by model.
How do I get the custom model data?

Are you saying that your custom Account_Model registration doesn't work? Were you able to do a add-migration "AddCustomProperties" and update-database commands to add your custom fields to your Identity table?

oh shiiiii, o yeah, let me try

wait no what am i saying, yes i were able to do migration. But i cant access the model since im on the Login. In this line:
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
It looks if Input Email in Login Form is = IdentityUser not on Account_Model. so the variable "user" is basically an IdentityUser, i cant access the Account_Model. But in breakpoint the user variable have Account_Model, i dont understand how.
I want to access the Account_Model of current logging in user.

Is the error from setup?

In the login cshtml page, what is being imported for signinmanager and usermanager? If it's IdentityUser, update it to your model.

I did that already, tried every fix i could think. Account_Model is the custom model, below the question is the line of codes i've post. and tried. I don't understand why it doesnt work, i did migration too by the way, when changing the identitydbcontext.

maybe ill just give up on this one.
